# Running Java Application NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, command-line, terminal

When I run my program from terminal by executing the command `java rmiserver.LightBulbServer.class` I'm getting **NoClassDefFoundError** :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rmiserver/LightBulbSe
rver/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rmiserver.LightBulbServer.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: rmiserver.LightBulbServer.class.  Program will ex
it.
```

Comment: That's a bad thing that you are getting an exception. And is there something you would like to ask about because you know this is a programming related Q&A site: you ask a question, you get an answer?

Comment: Post your command line (but I'm 100% sure I already know your problem, .class should not be included)

Comment: @Kevin same thing I was thinking

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely running the application like this:

```
java rmiserver.LightBulbServer.class
```

You shouldn't add the `.class` extension when running your program; use only the name of the class:

```
java rmiserver.LightBulbServer
```

Answer (score 1):

You're running the command:

```
java rmiserver.LightBulbServer.class
```

when you should be running

```
java rmiserver.LightBulbServer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some variables before Java can do anything on a system. This is why some people create batch files to get their Java programs running without modifying system variables.

But this usually happens because you didn't set the **CLASSPATH**.

For example, here is something that may or may not work:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\jdk1.5.0_06
set PATH=C:\jdk1.5.0_06\bin;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32
set CLASSPATH=.

java -jar myprogram.jar
```

Or try this command:

```
java -jar myprogram.jar -classpath .
```